# Why is such a large int (uint32) used for the transaction version field

Tags: block, raw-transaction

The transaction version field is a unsigned 32 bit integer. [[Source Code]](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/primitives/transaction.h#L268) [[Docs]](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#transactions)

This will allow for 0 through 4,294,967,295 (2^32 − 1) versions. So far, only versions 0, 1, 2 have been used. It seems that the amount of storage for this field is wasteful. Surely unsigned 8 bit integer would be more than enough. What was the rational for using such a large integer?

Could this be reduced with a new block version? Could this be done without a hard fork?

Answer (score 2):

> What was the rational for using such a large integer?

Because Satoshi did not care about it. Bitcoin transaction serialization is not optimized for size.

> Could this be reduced with a new block version?

No

> Could this be done without a hard fork?

No. But you can implement new way to serialize data on disk and on network and encode/decode transaction contents on-the-fly. In fact nobody cares about these bytes.